# r reshape with nulls when combination doesn't exist

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

I have some data I `melt` and `dcast` using the `reshape2` package, as follows.

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob"),
              Month = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2),
              Product = c("Car", "Bike", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Bike", "Bike"),
              Price = c(1000, 150, 300, 500, 2000, 200, 100))
#    Name Month Product Price
# 1 Alice     1     Car  1000
# 2 Alice     1    Bike   150
# 3 Alice     1     Car   300
# 4 Alice     2     Car   500
# 5   Bob     1     Car  2000
# 6   Bob     2    Bike   200
# 7   Bob     2    Bike   100

dat_melt <- melt(dat, id=c("Name", "Month", "Product"))
#    Name Month Product variable value
# 1 Alice     1     Car    Price  1000
# 2 Alice     1    Bike    Price   150
# 3 Alice     1     Car    Price   300
# 4 Alice     2     Car    Price   500
# 5   Bob     1     Car    Price  2000
# 6   Bob     2    Bike    Price   200
# 7   Bob     2    Bike    Price   100

dat_spread <- dcast(dat_melt, Name + Month ~ Product + variable, value.var="value", fun=sum)
#    Name Month Bike_Price Car_Price
# 1 Alice     1        150      1300
# 2 Alice     2          0       500
# 3   Bob     1          0      2000
# 4   Bob     2        300         0
```

How can I have this output such that the cases where the Name-Month-Product combination doesn't exist (e.g. Alice, 2, Bike) returns a `NULL` or `NA` rather than `0`? Note, the solution should work for cases where the `Price` is 0, so e.g. `dat_spread$BikePrice[BikePrice == 0] <- NA` would not be acceptable.

I have tried using anonymous functions in `dcast` to no avail, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
dcast(dat_melt, Name + Month ~ Product + variable, value.var="value",
      fun.aggregate = function(x) if_else(is.na(x), NULL, sum(x)))
#  Error: `false` must be type NULL, not double 

dcast(dat_melt, Name + Month ~ Product + variable, value.var="value",
      fun.aggregate = function(x) if_else(is.na(x), 3.14, sum(x))) # then update after
# Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be length 0,
# but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

Note, `reshape2` isn't a requirement, so if you have a solution that doesn't use it (e.g. using `tidyverse` functions) that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the value to use for missing combinations in `dcast` with the `fill` argument:

```
dcast(dat_melt, Name + Month ~ Product + variable,
      value.var = "value", fun = sum, fill = NA_real_)
#>    Name Month Bike_Price Car_Price
#> 1 Alice     1        150      1300
#> 2 Alice     2         NA       500
#> 3   Bob     1         NA      2000
#> 4   Bob     2        300        NA
```

Created on 2018-03-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

(Note that under the hood, `dcast` calls `vapply`, which is picky about types; so just specifying `fill = NA` isn't good enough, as `typeof(NA) == "logical"` and your values are numeric: you have to explicitly use a "double" NA with `NA_real_`)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative: You can also do all the reshaping with `dplyr`+`tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
dat %>%
    group_by(Name, Month, Product) %>%
    summarise(Price = sum(Price)) %>%
    spread(Product, Price);
## A tibble: 4 x 4
## Groups:   Name, Month [4]
#  Name  Month  Bike   Car
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Alice    1.  150. 1300.
#2 Alice    2.   NA   500.
#3 Bob      1.   NA  2000.
#4 Bob      2.  300.   NA
```

Similarly to `dcast`, `spread` has a `fill` argument, which is `fill=NA` by default.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for this answer. Side note, do your doubles print with decimal points after them like in your answer? Mine specify <dbl> but print the same as integers. Is that something you set up specifically?

Comment: The printing of doubles with the decimal point is a feature in a recently released [new version of _pillar_](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/03/pillar-1-2-1/), the package that controls tibble printing.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Thanks for the clarification; I had no idea.